# Does $\prod_k (x - r_k)^{m_k} = \prod_k (1 - \frac{x}{r_k})^{m_k}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, complex-numbers, generating-functions

I am trying to understand the last line in the excerpt below from my course notes. The discussion concerns an algorithm for turning a (compact, i.e. finite) expression for a generating function into a formula for the coefficients of the generating function.

> [image]

The "we can express" part of the last line is giving me trouble. I cannot see why the two products are equal. Is there something obvious I'm missing? I see that they are both equal at $x = 0$, and that we can put $r_k$ in the denominator when we know none of the $r_k$ equal $0$, but why are the two expressions equal? I don't get it.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The products are not the same, but $g(x)=\lambda\prod_k (x-r_k)^{m_k}$ where $\lambda$ is a constant. $g(0)=1$ means that $\lambda\prod_k(-r_k)^{m_k}=1$ and thus $\lambda=\prod_k\frac{1}{(-r_k)^{m_k}}$. Therefore $$ g(x)=\prod_k\frac{(x-r_k)^{m_k}}{(-r_k)^{m_k}}=\prod_{k}\left(1-\frac{x}{r_k}\right)^{m_k} $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought $g(x) = \prod_k (x - r_k)^{m_k}$, though. Am I misreading the text? It says "express $g(x)$ as a product of irreducible factors." Where do you get the $\lambda$ from?

Comment: Or maybe we're supposed to factor the constant $\lambda$ out of $g(x)$ at the outset. Maybe the leading term in the polynomial is supposed have a coefficient of $1$. I think that might be it.

Comment: Expressing $g(x)$ as a product of irreductible factors means that $g(x)=\prod Q_k(x)$ where $Q_k$ are irreductible factors. In this case $Q_k$ can be written as $Q_k(x)=\lambda_k(x-r_k)^{m_k}$. Regrouping all the constants in the front leads to such a $\lambda$, which indeed is the leading term of the polynomial. Here there is no assumptions on the leading coefficient of $g$, in fact you only need one condition on $g$ ($g(0)=1$ for instance) to get the value of $\lambda$.